# JAVA | Como nombro "alias" las columnas de un array

Tags: java, array, oracle, jdeveloper

Extraigo los datos desde *SQL* y los inserto en un *Array en Java*, quiero cambiarle el nombre a la columna por otro que se vea mejor, ejemplo la columna **nombre_tecnico** quiero que figure el encabezado de la columna como **Nombre**. También me gustaría saber si se puede modificar el tamaño del array si puedo hacer las columnas mas anchas por ejemplo.
Probé consultando con *ALIAS AS* desde *SQL* pero no funciona, parece que lo tengo que hacer en Java.

Código:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class BuscarTecnicoMySQL {
    public BuscarTecnicoMySQL() {
            super();
            }
            private String ultimoMensajeMySQL="";

            public String buscarTecnico(String asterisco) {
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet conjuntoResultados = null;
            String SQL = "SELECT "+asterisco+" FROM tecnico";
            try {
            st = Conexion.getConexion().createStatement();
            conjuntoResultados = st.executeQuery(SQL);
            ResultSetMetaData metaDatos = conjuntoResultados.getMetaData();
            int numeroDeColumnas = metaDatos.getColumnCount();
            ultimoMensajeMySQL = "Columnas = " + numeroDeColumnas + "\n";
            for ( int i = 1; i <= numeroDeColumnas; i++ ) {
            ultimoMensajeMySQL = ultimoMensajeMySQL + metaDatos.getColumnName(i) + "\t";
            }
            ultimoMensajeMySQL = ultimoMensajeMySQL + "\n";
            while ( conjuntoResultados.next() ) {
            for ( int i = 1; i <= numeroDeColumnas; i++ ) {
            ultimoMensajeMySQL = ultimoMensajeMySQL + conjuntoResultados.getObject( i ) + "\t";
            }
            ultimoMensajeMySQL = ultimoMensajeMySQL + "\n";
            }   
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            ultimoMensajeMySQL="Error: " + e.getMessage();
            }
            return ultimoMensajeMySQL;
            }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya intentaste usando as? select nombre_tecnico as "Nombre Tecnico" from tecnico

Comment: Ya lo intenté con AS y nada